# How to properly dispose of old fuel?

Tags: fuel-system, recycle

I have some old 2 stroke mixed gas I need to get rid of.  This could also apply to old fuel removed from a sitting car or any vehicle for that matter.  What is the proper way to dispose of this?  Are recycling centers common?  I think once in the past, I gave some to an auto repair shop and they just put it in their oil/gas burner heater.

Comment: what about a match? :-)

Comment: Give it to some teenagers. They'll find something to do with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any oil change place should be able to take it off your hands for a small disposal fee.  You can also try calling your local fire department, they may either be able to take it, or they will know of a licensed disposal site in your area.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how old it is (<1 year for me) i have always just mixed it with fresh fuel and used it like normal. No problems. Fuel older than a year makes a great grease cutter, it does a great job at loosening up bolts, old parts, and grease and crud off of skin.

Be sure not to use in enclosed spaces, only recommended to use outdoors.

Comment: Less than one year isn't really old, and mixed 2-stroke fuel has a hard expiration.

Answer (score 4):

So long as it is clean and just old, put it in your nearly full car tank. A small amount of 2-cycle oil will not matter diluted from say 50:1 to say 2500:1. In driving 5000Km you might use 500L of fuel and perhaps 0.25L of engine oil. That's a ratio of 2000:1, so adding a bit of 2-stroke mix won't harm unless the 2-cycle oil used is particularly bad for your catalytic converter.

Even if your car uses diesel, a 2% gasoline mix will do no harm. VW used to recommend a 25% gasoline mix to stop the diesel freezing in the Canadian winter.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly in the UK there are hundreds of recycling centres that will take oil and fuel, as it is against the law to dispose of it other than through an approved centre.

Answer (score 2):

One can dispose of used engine oil at any Jiffy Lube for free.

Answer (score 2):

Mix it with fresh gas and burn it in a lawn mower.  If it's straight gas, mix it with fresh and burn in a beater vehicle.