# What do I do after adding extra oil/gas mixture into the car, which now won't start?

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, cranks-wont-run, 4runner

The car, (Toyota 4Runner), won't start after we put some old oil/fuel in. We had read that it's fine to do with unneeded oil. We topped off the tank with regular gas to dilute it, but still not starting.

Do we need to siphon out all the gas? If so, where do we put a whole tank full of gas when the car is stuck in a parking lot?

Edit: It looks like it's not possible to siphon from this car.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does it sound like it wants to run at all? I mean, does it sputter/cough at all? Did it run just fine before you put the gas into it?

Comment: It ran fine before adding the fuel. Now, it sputters like it's almost able to start but not quite.

Comment: On hold with AAA now to see what they can do.

Comment: Are you saying you added engine oil to the fuel?

Comment: Where did you read it was fine to do this? And how much did you add? Did you poor it directly into the tank or mix it with good fuel?

Comment: Why not throw a gallon of Diesel and a pint of Olive Oil in there while you're at it? (JOKE! DON'T DO THAT!). There is absolutely no sense in putting old oil/fuel into a car, and I don't know where you would have read that. You're probably going to have to drop the gas tank to empty and flush it.

Comment: Took it to Tuffy and they cleaned out something in the fuel system and it works.

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/728/29274 https://community.cartalk.com/t/disposal-of-one-gallon-of-gas-mixed-with-two-cycle-engine-oil/64328/7 Of course it was over 6 months old, so maybe that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like this Q has been answered...